# gitlab-ci.yml include project from environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible, to dynamically change project with environment variable?

Something like:

```
include:
  - project: $STAGE_PROJECT_PATH
    file: '/job.yml'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GitLab 13.8 and above you should be able to use variables in the `include` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Refer to the documentation for examples:

> [Use variables with `include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include)

Comment: In the example, i found my mistake. Environment variable must be with quotes. 
project: '$STAGE_PROJECT_PATH' - this works. Thank you